# How can I change the page depth when using screen on iterm2 to connect to a router?

Tags: macos, router, display, terminal, iterm2

Let's say I'm connecting to a router with 'screen' through a terminal (iterm2) and I want to view a log or a configuration. It will only display 1 page at a time and I have to press Enter or Space to view the next line/page.

Is there a command I can configure that will just display the entire output? I'm recording the terminal output to a log.txt file to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `screen` utility shouldn't have any bearing on how logs are displayed in your terminal. `Screen` is just a [terminal multiplexer](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_termmux.php) and doesn't change how your shell behaves inherently. Log output is no exception: this behaviour is up to the command you've executed to view the log once you're within a `screen` instance. I'll try to provide some solutions for common `screen` use-cases and how to change the log output:

**1:** If you have `screen` running without any options then log output is simply up to the specific command you're using to view the log in that moment and there are many others at your disposal. The behaviour you've described sounds like a `more` or `less` command.

To view the entire file at once, try the **cat** command:

```
cat log.txt
```

Here's a [pretty detailed article](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/08/10-awesome-examples-for-viewing-huge-log-files-in-unix/) describing other commands to output logs.

**2:** If you've started `screen` as a daemon(which will start `screen`, run some command automatically in the background, and return shell control to you i.e. `screen -dmS name-of-screen-instance command-to-run --options`), then you'll just want to specify some other command to use

**3:** If you have some other setup or have used `screen` in some other way that has an impact on how your logs display, please include more detail in your question by editing it. As a suggestion, try including the steps you've taken with all the commands you've entered up until now, verbatim.

Also useful: [Screen command examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/)

Comment: Thanks, it was actually the line setting in the router itself